# When this NSDictionary calls initWithArray, why does it contain 0 objects?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm writing an app to review Latin verb conjugations, but I'm hitting a snag.  I create an array of endings, but when I try to initialize an `NSDictionary` with those endings, the `count` of the dictionary is always 0.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's `BlackBox.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BlackBox : NSObject

@property (weak) NSDictionary *setOfEndings;

- (void)determineEndingsToUse;

@end
```

Here's the relevant method from `BlackBox.m`:

```
- (void)determineEndingsToUse
{
NSArray *keys=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"first person singular", @"second person singular", @"third person singular", @"first person plural", @"second person plural", @"third person singular", nil];
NSArray *endingsPossible = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ō", @"ās", @"at", @"āmus", @"ātis", @"ant",  nil];
NSLog(@"endingsPossible count: %d", endingsPossible.count);  //This logs 6, correctly.
if (!self.setOfEndings)
{
    self.setOfEndings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:endingsPossible forKeys:keys];
}
NSLog(@"setOfEndings count: %d",self.setOfEndings.count); //This logs 0 instead of 6.  Why?
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: have you tried to debug by checking debugger goes into if condition? or line of dictionary allocation is executed or not

Comment: have you tried creating a strong reference to the NSDictionary object? Setting it to nonatomic might also be a good idea though not related to your particular case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As setOfEndings is a weak pointer, it will be released immediately, as there is no strong reference to the allocated dictionary.

You can make it to work by changing reference to strong or change as below:

```
 NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:endingsPossible forKeys:keys];
 self.setOfEndings = dict;

//By default dict is a strong reference to the allocated dictionary.
```

Comment: Thank you so much--that did it!  Now of course other issues have come up, but those are for a new question....